# commit to heroku Git, but no changes in myapp.heroku.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

In the `facefancheck` directory,

```
>git add .
>git commit -m "facefancheck"
>git push heroku
```

In a random directory,

```
>git clone git@heroku.com:facefancheck.git
>cd facefancheck
>rails s
```

I get the thing I want in `127.0.0.1:3000`, but not in `facefancheck.heroku.com`.
So, why `facefancheck.heroku.com` did not run the same as git@heroku.com:facefancheck.git?
Did I not update the heroku correctly from Git? Or?

Comment: Have you created the database? `heroku rake db:create` and `heroku rake db:migrate`

Comment: haven't , It is necessary for facefancheck.heroku.com to use the code from git@heroku.com:facefancheck.git ? will try can let you know.

Comment: heroku rake db:create >>> ulwbdzzqbf already exists
(in /disk1/home/slugs/338566_7ac114e_8bc4-75aee246-fb13-4127-8121-2ed06062e4a8/mnt). so as heroku rake db:migrate. After this , facefancheck.heroku.com still the same

Comment: When I visit facefancheck.heroku.com, I can see a date printed. Is it normal now?

Comment: i rename to fancheck.heroku.com then ok d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh, I solved it already. It is because I renamed in the web, but didn't update the local Git.
So, I have to rename the name to `fancheck` and it works,

```
heroku rename fancheck
```

But when I switch back to `facefancheck`, the same problem again,

```
heroku rename facefancheck
```